# I like spaghetti

Tags: riddle, word

I'm not Budha, Jahweh, Allah or Zeus, yet they call me God.

The third under this name, but I go under more than one.

One by the rank of a policeman, one where I'm the skinny guy and one sweet as candy.

I'm born to work in a company using SCRUM, but people try to impersonate me.

I could give you 13 * 10<sup>3</sup>m reasons why you should use the metric system, but this time you need the inferior imperial system.

You don't scare me.

**Bonus hint**

> I am a real person 
>  **bonus bonus** check my profile description for another clue

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! General note: hints shouldn't really be posted straight away, but rather after a couple of days if no-one has solved it

Comment: Upvote for bonus bonus hint.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks, I appreciate the advice! Are there some guidelines what is considered a real hint and what is considered some extra info for the question?

Comment: @ThomasMoors Is the bonus bonus hint meant to be a joke or an actual hint?  If it doesn't relate to the puzzle then I suggest removing it.

Comment: @MikeQ It's just a joke, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> Eminem

I'm not Budha, Jahweh, Allah or Zeus, yet they call me God.

> Rap God

The third under this name, but I go under more than one. One by the rank of a policeman, one where I'm the skinny guy and one sweet as candy.

> Slim, Marshall, Eminem (From OP: His full name is Marshall Bruce Mathers III)

I'm born to work in a company using SCRUM, but people try to impersonate me.

> Would the REAL Slim Shady please "stand up" in the scrum meeting :)

I could give you 13 * 103m reasons why you should use the metric system, but this time you need the inferior imperial system.

> 8 miles

Don't scare me

> Song: "I'm not afraid"

Spaghetti:

> "Knees weak palms sweaty... Vomit on my shirt; mom's spaghetti."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)

Comment: Yeah... I'm actually CSM. Just needed to run through my knowledge.

Comment: P.S. for `The third under this name` was because his real name is *Marshall Bruce Mathers III*